# test JNI on Hadoop using MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, java-native-interface

[I try to run a JNI program on Hadoop using MapReduce.Here is the command:

> bin/hadoop jar /Users/ming/Desktop/mctest/mctest.jar -files /Users/ming/Desktop/mctest/libGenerateRandom.jnilib mc hdfs://localhost:9000/Users/ming/seeds_shuffle.txt hdfs://localhost:9000/Users/ming/output

The jnilib(It's a file on Mac OS X just like .so file on Linux) should be sent to tasknode with the jar file.But I got an error below:][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8xXF.png)

Anyone can help?
Thanks.

Comment: the error is : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -files
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)

Answer (score 0):

Instead use:

```
bin/hadoop jar /Users/ming/Desktop/mctest/mctest.jar \
<main-class> \
-files /Users/ming/Desktop/mctest/libGenerateRandom.jnilib \
mc \
hdfs://localhost:9000/Users/ming/seeds_shuffle.txt \     
hdfs://localhost:9000/Users/ming/output
```

Where `<main-class>` should be of the form `com.you.MainRunner`.

That's because it's expecting the package to appear before any additional arguments such as `-file`.